# Codeigniter 2: Why does $this->db->get('documents') return false?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I just started using CodeIgniter 2 and probably I have overseen something obvious but I can't figure it out.

My MySQL Database has a table named Documents with a column named online_since.

Function _getMaxOnlineSince() should get the maximum online_since value and return it as a string.

In application/models/browse_model.php:

```
  private function _getMaxOnlineSince() {
    $this->db->select_max('online_since');
    $oQuery = $this->db->get('documents');
    return $oQuery->num_rows() > 0 ? $oQuery->row()->online_since : false;
  }
```

And I get an error message in the Browser:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function num_rows() on
>   boolean

because of $oQuery is false: var_dump($oQuery) returns bool(false)

var_dump($this->db->select_max('online_since')) returns object(CI_DB_mysqli_driver)#14 (73) {...}

The Codeigniter 2 application worked on the old server with PHP5.3 but after the update to PHP 7 it crashes on this point.

Why does $this->db->get('documents') return false and how can I fix it?

I could manage to get this function work with sql queries:

```
  private function _getMaxOnlineSince() {
    $oQuery = "select max(online_since) from documents";
    $sMaxOnlineSinceDate = $this->db->query($oQuery);
    return $sMaxOnlineSinceDate->num_rows() > 0 ? $sMaxOnlineSinceDate->row()->online_since : false;
  }
```

But there are many more places where I use

> $this->db->get('documents')

I suppose in my case CodeIgniter has trouble to evaluate this statement for some reason. I'll debug further.

Comment: what does `print_r($oQuery->result())` return?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function result() on boolean

Comment: is the table empty?

Comment: in table Documents are 2000 rows.

Comment: think you need to find out what has changed between php 5.3 and 7.0 in relation to CI. check the system files, maybe there are some CI function now deprecated. You also may want to upgrade to 3.0, at least to check if it works with the new version of CI: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrading.html

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your function **_getMaxOnlineSince()** in below manner

```
private function _getMaxOnlineSince() {
$this->db->select_max('id','online_since');
$res1 = $this->db->get('documents');
if ($res1->num_rows() > 0) {
    return $res1->row();
}
else {
    return false
}
return NULL;
```

}

Also please check whether the table name **documents** is correct. Hope this will help you

Comment: in your example $res1 would be still false.
the table documents exists.

Comment: I have implemented the above code in my local by taking two fields id and name and inserted two static records. When I print $res1->row(); then the output is stdClass Object ( [name] => 2 ). So please check once it's working for me